# SQL LAG function over dates

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have the following table (example):

```
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+
| id | value | last_update | ingestion_date |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+
| 1  | 30    | 2021-02-03  | 2021-02-07     |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+
| 1  | 29    | 2021-02-03  | 2021-02-06     |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+
| 1  | 28    | 2021-01-25  | 2021-02-02     |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+
| 1  | 25    | 2021-01-25  | 2021-02-01     |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+
| 1  | 23    | 2021-01-20  | 2021-01-31     |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+
| 1  | 20    | 2021-01-20  | 2021-01-30     |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+
| 2  | 55    | 2021-02-03  | 2021-02-06     |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+
| 2  | 50    | 2021-01-25  | 2021-02-02     |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+
```

The result I need:
It should be the last updated value in the column value and the penult value (based in the last_update and ingestion_date) in the value2.

```
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
| id | value | last_update | ingestion_date | value2 |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
| 1  | 30    | 2021-02-03  | 2021-02-07     | 28     |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
| 2  | 55    | 2021-02-03  | 2021-02-06     | 50     |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
```

The query I have right now is the following:

```
SELECT id, value, last_update, ingestion_date, value2
FROM
(SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY last_update DESC, ingestion_date DESC) AS order,
        LAG(value) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY last_update, ingestion_date) AS value2
    FROM table)
WHERE ordem = 1
```

The result I am getting:

```
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
| ID | value | last_update | ingestion_date | value2 |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
| 1  | 30    | 2021-02-03  | 2021-02-07     | 29     |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
| 2  | 55    | 2021-02-03  | 2021-02-06     | 50     |
+----+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
```

Obs: I am using Athena from AWS

Comment: Your expected 28 is not the penultimate value for id = 1, it's 29, so the db provides you with that result. 

You can pass an offset to LAG, like `LAG(value, 2) OVER ( .... )` will lag two rows instead of one.